# How to go back to previous fragment from activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got an app with nav drawer, which is switching fragments. From inside one of those fragments, I am calling a new activity. When I click back in this activity (in toolbar), I want to go back to previous selected fragment but instead it puts me back to first fragment. I am adding my fragment to back stack so this should not be a problem.

Here is what I have already tried:

I have overriden the onBackPressed method in my 2nd activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        this.finish();
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

It is not working. I also saved index of current fragment inside onsaveinstancestate method and retrieve it but same result. I also tried with always putting current fragment inside variable and try to reshow it but still, it does not work. Anything else I could try?

Fun fact: if I press back inside bottom panel, it does actually goes back to previous fragment.

EDIT: Here is my code for doing this:

```
 private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment)
 {
     if (fragment != null)
     {
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         manager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

I add first fragment only, if savedInstanceState is null, like so:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // first time
    mTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.home);
    replaceFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance()); 
}
```

And yes, all this is done inside onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, that people are still trying to help me. This answer helped me fix my problem: [Android - Navigation Up from Activity to Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059474/android-navigation-up-from-activity-to-fragment/30059708#30059708)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and got fixed. The only thing you need to do is to 
override the method "onOptionsItemSelected" in the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

android.R.id.home is your first fragment in the menu.

Answer (score 4):

What I tend to do is this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        this.finish();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed(); //replaced
    }
}
```

This way it handles the fragment stuff on its own within, but when there's no fragments left to go back to, then it finishes the activity.

EDIT: UP navigation can recreate your previous activity even if it already exists. To prevent that from happening, redefine the `Up` navigation's event in `onOptionsItemSelected` like so:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent parentIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            if(parentIntent == null) { 
                finish();
                return true;
            } else {
                parentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(parentIntent);
                finish();
                return true;
            }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Still not working. I guess I did wrong something else.

Comment: When I press back inside second activity, it goes back to first one and shows up first fragment, not second one.

Comment: Are you also adding the first fragment to the stack, and also the second? Are you using `add` or `replace`? Are you adding the fragment only if the save instance state is null? Are you doing this in onCreate? Post the code for the first activity's relevant methods.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh..... wait a second, so you're trying to use UP Navigation to go back. Hold on, I have a fix for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30059708/2413303

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

When you call an activity from other activity's fragment, then the previous activity's instance state that is the calling activity which was having fragment's instance state will be saved in stack...so all u need to do is finish the called activity and u will have the fragment from which you called your second activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment. So I have to guess. I once had the same issue.
Sounds like a problem related to the activity lifecycle (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle). Be sure to add your first fragment only once, because your activity's fragment manager is capable of the lifecycle.
Thus, the statement that adds the first fragment to your fragment manager should be surrounded by `if (savedInstanceState == null) { ... }`.

Comment: I took care of that:
`if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.home);
            replaceFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance()); `

Answer (score 0):

Override `onOptionsItemSelected` method in activity as follows,

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call new Activity from Fragment you should write :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getFragment().getContext(),NewActivity.class);
getFragment().getContext().startActivity(intent);

FragmentManager fm = CurrentFragment.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack(CurrentFragment.class.getName()).commit();
fm.executePendingTransactions();
```

It Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                           .addToBackStack("home") // should not be null
                           .replace(binding.fragmentContainer.getId(), new HomeFragment())
                           .commit();
```

Pass name in **addToBackStack(String name)** method. This function add fragment into backstack if passed name is not null. App automatically start managing backstack of fragment

Remove your override **onBackPressed()** method. No use of it now