# Close the currrent fragment and open the previous one

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

Imagine i have a frameLayout in my main activity, and two fragments,
so now first fragment is being displayed, i replaced it with secondFragment and added first one to back stack, now some condition is met in the secondfragment so i want to close the second fragment and open the first one where we left that (basically back from the back stack) without pressing the back button. how do i achieve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491093/how-to-go-back-to-previous-fragment-from-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write this code for removing current fragment from backstack:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: this will replace the current fragment with the stack fragment (in the framelayout)?

Comment: yes , if you add your fragments in back stack you can switch back to previous fragment with this code. also for your information, if you use 'replace' while changing fragments, onCreateView called again when you pop back stack, but if you use 'add' previous state will be kept when you switch back to previous fragment.

Comment: "but if you use 'add' previous state will be kept when you switch back to previous fragment. "
But when i use add instead of replace the fragment one stays while fragment two overlaps it

Comment: Yes you are right, you should use replace if you dont need fragments overlapping or keeping it's state.

Comment: i want to keep the state but i dont want it overlapping. is that possible ?

Comment: unfortunately no, you just have two options, add fragments on top of each other, or replace them and handle onCreateView method.